# Patterns for Methods to be used by Insert and Update

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to find out efficient designs to use for a method that can be used by both Insert and Update triggers. For example: if I want to perform some complex logic when an Opportunity is inserted with a Closed Won stage OR if it is updated to a Closed Won stage (from a non Closed Won stage). The goal, of course, being code reuse.

I am aware of a couple solutions, but are there any best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few efficient ways to handle this. Historically, I've always just initialized each record with an empty record on insert, which means there's only one conditional to check. For example, given your "if moving to closed won, or inserted as closed won" hypothetical, I might write:

```
Opportunity[] matchingRecords = new Opportunity[0];
for(Integer index = 0; index < Trigger.size; index++) {
  Opportunity oldRecord = Trigger.isInsert? new Opportunity(): Trigger.old[index];
  Opportunity newRecord = Trigger.new[index];
  if(newRecord.IsWon && oldRecord.IsWon != newRecord.IsWon) {
    matchingRecords.add(newRecord);
  }
}
```

Be aware, however, that constructing a new object means you get some default values. For example, IsWon defaults to false, so if you're checking for false, this won't work on inserts as you expect. This is rare, but worth knowing that this isn't exactly 100% "safe."

You can also use the Safe Navigation Operator (SNO) if you prefer:

```
Opportunity[] matchingRecords = new Opportunity[0];
for(Integer index = 0; index < Trigger.size; index++) {
  Opportunity newRecord = Trigger.new[index];
  if(newRecord.IsWon && Trigger.old?.get(0).IsWon != newRecord.IsWon) {
    matchingRecords.add(Trigger.new[index]);
  }
}
```

I've traditionally disliked the `List.get(index)` method, because it is twice as slow as accessing an index directly, but here, SNO actually improves performance by taking out the ternary operator and extra assignment.

In general, it's possible to funnel both insert and update logic through a single method often by adding a single default value somewhere. Other more advanced techniques are also possible, but are likely overkill for small projects.

One interesting concept could be a library of methods that can do filtering. I've build a few of them over the years. One of them went something like this:

```
sObject[] matchingRecords = Data.filter(
  Trigger.old, 
  Trigger.new)
.diff(Opportunity.IsWon)
.equalValue(Opportunity.IsWon, Data.OPERATOR.EQUALS, true)
.getRecords();
```

You could then just work on the records that matched. You could get as crazy as you want, but like I said, this is probably overkill for most projects. If you want simple and efficient, using SNO is probably the way to go in modern code.